# Convert specific number date to show month

Tags: perl, scripting, sed, awk, tr

Want to convert for example that date:

```
02082012

In that case:
02 - Day
08 - Month
2012 - Year
```

For now I separate the date but not able to convert into month:

```
#echo "02082012"|gawk -F "" '{print $1$2 "-" $3$4 "-" $5$6$7$8}'
#02-08-2012
```

Expected view after convert and to catch all Months:

```
02-Aug-2012
```

Comment: You can do this: `date -d'08/02/2012' "+%d-%b-%Y"` that gives `02-Aug-2012`

Comment: In that case I get input in that format `02082012`

Comment: Yes, I see, the problem I got is that "02082012" is not an accepted format for `date`.

Comment: why do you use the perl tag? The question is not related to Perl.

Comment: May be you're right, but in the most cases I put perl because try to learn language also ... sorry if that offense to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

straightforward:

```
kent$ date -d "$(echo '02082012'|sed -r 's/(..)(..)(....)/\3-\2-\1/')" "+%d-%b-%Y"
02-Aug-2012
```

Answer (score 3):

Another Perl sollution with the [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module, which is in the Perl core.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $date = '02082012';
print strftime( '%d-%b-%Y', 0, 0, 0,
  substr( $date, 0, 2 ),
  substr( $date, 2, 2 ) - 1,
  substr( $date, 4, 4 ) - 1900 );
```

Look at http://strftime.net/ for a very nice overview of what the placeholders to `strftime` do.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl’s POSIX module and `strftime` looks like

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw/ strftime /;

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  if (my($d,$m,$y) = /^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)$/) {
    print strftime("%d-%b-%Y", 0, 0, 0, $d, $m-1, $y-1900), "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
$ echo 02082012 | convert-date
02-Aug-2012
```

Answer (score 2):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) is a core Perl module and is great for simple manipulations like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;

my $string = '02082012';

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($string, '%d%m%Y');

say $date->strftime('%d-%b-%Y');
```

(Yes, this is very similar to user1811486's answer - but it uses the correct formats as requested in the original question.)

Answer (score 1):

I think like this.....

```
use 5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $date = '2013-04-07';
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%Y-%m-%d');
print $t->month;
print $t->strftime('%Y-%b-%d');
```

Just I tried this ...

Answer (score 1):

To break apart a string with fixed field lengths, use `unpack`:

```
my $input = "02082012";
my ( $day, $month, $year ) = unpack( 'a2 a2 a4', $input );
print "$input becomes $day, $month, $year\n";
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html

Then, as stated in the other answers, use `POSIX::strftime()` to reformat the date.